# Importing only one user data from a Dump file

Tags: import, oracle11g, database-administration, impdp

I am using oracle 11gr1 SingleByte Database,

I am trying to import a Dump file. but strangely the dump file contains multiple user objects(i.e, Import(IMPDP) is not done properly).

```
example:
. . "TEST"."AUDVALUES"                     174.5 MB 2136286 rijen geëxporteerd
. . "TRAIN"."AUDVALUES"                    105.5 MB 1311686 rijen geëxporteerd
```

I want to import only TEST objects not TRAIN objects to target DB?
Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: then why you din't try schema import and export?

Comment: @ThiyaguATR,The provided dump is generated from EXPDP, So i cant use Normal IMPORT now

Comment: 'm sorry...what i meant was...have u tried EXPDP and IMPDP for particular schema?

Comment: yes, I have tried EXPDP, But it is importing both the objects TEST and TRAIN
though i have tried
REMAP_SCHEMA=TEST:TARGETTEST

Comment: can you tell the steps your using for this?